# Windows 8 password, ctrl-backspace

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, passwords, password-recovery

An acquaintance of mine just bought a new laptop today. On Windows 7, he has been used to using the character generated by Ctrl-Backspace(ASCII 127) in his password. In fact, his password was simply 3 times this character, because he figured it would be hard to guess.

So he boots up his new laptop that has Windows 8 on it, and uses the same password when creating a user account. This works fine here. However, when he tries to log on, the Ctrl-Backspace combination does not work. Neither does using alt+numpad to enter the keycode. 
So now he is simply unable to log on to his brand new computer, and there was no windows 8 disk accompanying it so he would be able to reset/reinstall.

Is there anything he can do? Or does he have to take it back to the retailer?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is obviously a bug -- where does one file bugs for Windows 8?

Comment: Its tough not to chuckle, :) .No its definitely not a bug, you friend needs to do a password recovery. There are several ways to do it, infact you might find it here on SU.

Comment: Using a boot disk of [TRK](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) should provide an account unlocker.

Comment: Also, in all honesty that's a horrible password, DELDELDEL? or ⌂⌂⌂ is only slightly less guessable then aaa, bbb etc...

Comment: There aren't many computers anymore that even come with the recovery disk; however, the majority have a recovery partition.  You may need to google the key combo to enter it, but usually on boot it is one of the `F-keys`.

Answer (score 7):

Try holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then type `127` in via the *Numpad* on your keyboard.  Let go of the Alt key and it should insert ASCII character 127. Repeat twice more to get three of them.

Note: ASCII 127 is the "Delete" code.  So often it will do what it's supposed to and delete a character instead of displaying the 'box' (because it's an unprintable ASCII Code with no actual symbol). So you may just be out-of-luck.

Related SU question: [Ctrl+Backspace inserts a small box instead of erasing](https://superuser.com/questions/33142/ctrlbackspace-inserts-a-small-box-instead-of-erasing)
Related question over on StackOverflow: [Which character is Ctrl+Backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377059/which-character-is-ctrlbackspace)